# Change the default backup time of WhatsApp messages

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger

The default backup time for WhatsApp is specific (in my case, it's 4:00 AM).

Although we can manually backup at any time, how do we change the default backup time?

Comment: What is more concerning, is that it is running at 02:00 UTC - meaning it does not account for local time and runs late evening or early morning.

Comment: It was backing up on 4am many years ago – a very nice time that few people will still messaging. But the automatic backup time has pushed forward to 3am and now 2am daily. A very inappropriate time to initiate a ten-minute long backup...

Answer (score 9):

Sadly, it cannot be done. WhatsApp doesn't allow any other time to be set for the automatic backup of messages.

Comment: That's right, sadly, even though it seems plain stupid to me.

Comment: I am often carrying on an important conversation when 02:00 strikes and I go offline for 5 minutes, invariably with catastrophic social consequences!

Comment: To me, this is the most annoying thing on WhatsApp, I'm always using WhatsApp at 2:00.

Comment: It is stupid. Because at 2:00 my phone is on airplane mode while I am sleeping. Then the backup is pushed at when I wake up at 7/8 am

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change the Whatsapp backup time to the local device storage. But optionally, you can have **Google drive** as your backup destination and can schedule it to backup as you wish (Monthly, Weekly, Daily or On click).

Google drive can backup your photos and videos along with the chat content in your Whatsapp account.

Comment: Yes but the backup is still done at the same time, so this doesn't help much.

Comment: Yeah backup is done as scheduled by whatsapp, its 2:00 in here.